# Understanding of the terminology "Inherit"

Tags: ssas

What is the definition of "Inherit" based on the picture?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I had to scale up that image quitte far to get an idea where you are. Cann't you also add a description of the tab/view/workflow you're in?

Comment: Right click on the picture and select image and you will retrieve a big picture. It works well for Firefox

Comment: Good for you! I'm not on FF...but that should be clear by now... :-)